# update state in React.js an nested objects of array

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, state

I was trying to make a school management application using Next.js. Here i encounter a problem during state updation.
I made a DUMMY_*DATA array like this and store in a state.* **const [Data, setData] = useState(DUMMY_DATA);** and pass to different components through props.

```
const DUMMY_DATA = [
  {
    id: 1,
    class: '10A',
    startingDate: '20.9.2024',
    totalPapers: 2,
    subjects: [
      { id: 1.1, subject: 'math', date: '2023-12-11', startingTime: '10:00 ' },
      { id: 1.2, subject: 'english', date: '2023-11-10', startingTime: '11:00 ' },
    ],
  },
]
```

> i am showing this data in the form of table

operations i am performing

1. add new Row on clicking [+] button
2. edit and delete perticular row which show subjects.

the operations are perform correctly [ checking through console statements ] but i am failing in updating this DUMMY_DATA through setData() function.

like for example:

This is my addNewRowHandler function to add new row

```
function addNewRowHandler() {
    const updateSubjects = [...subjects];
    const newRow = {
      id: +`${selectedClassID}.${subjects.length + 1}`,
      subject: '',
      date: '',
      startingTime: '',
    };
    updateSubjects.push(newRow);
    // setData((prevData) => {
    //   return prevData.map((data) => {
    //     if (data.id === selectedClassID) {
    //       return {
    //         ...data,
    //         subjects: updateSubjects,
    //       };
    //     }
    //     return data;
    //   });
    // });

    console.log('new row add krne pr ', updateSubjects);
  }
```

i tried to run this commented code but its not giving me results. same happening with other edit and update operations.

this is my full project link,  you can check the consoles and help me to solve this.

[https://codesandbox.io/p/github/pankajasiwal/school-Management-task/main?workspaceId=52eca021-a680-42b3-8589-510d736e373b](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/pankajasiwal/school-Management-task/main?import=true&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqarya7q0006356hcsgmlvij%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqarya7q0002356ho3s9sn3p%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqarya7q0004356hcg7ncba9%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqarya7q0005356hvx4zc1y7%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clqarya7q0002356ho3s9sn3p%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqarya7q0001356hylc8f6tc%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqarya7q0002356ho3s9sn3p%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqarya7q0001356hylc8f6tc%2522%257D%252C%2522clqarya7q0005356hvx4zc1y7%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqarya7q0005356hvx4zc1y7%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqas0v3s00g0356hnmhismo1%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqas0v3s00g0356hnmhismo1%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clqarya7q0004356hcg7ncba9%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqarya7q0004356hcg7ncba9%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqarycyi007b356htzqfjnc1%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqarya7q0003356hnuo9bej6%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clqary9z7000ueej92d4t97uo%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqarycyi007b356htzqfjnc1%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Note: This is also showing me hydration errors, so please also guide me on that.